# I am getting Error in Excel Dataconfig how can i resolve this error?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, data-driven

Here is my Code:au

```
package Mypackage;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xb.xmlconfig.ConfigDocument.Config;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

@Test(dataProvider="Rahul")
public class jh{
    WebDriver driver;
    public void loginjh(String loginId ,String password)throws InterruptedException {
    }
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\Selenium2017\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("URL");
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         driver.findElement(By.name("loginId")).sendKeys("loginId");
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password");
         driver.findElement(By.name("btnSubmit")).click();
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }


@DataProvider(name="Rahul")
public Object[][] TestData()

***Excel Dataconfig config = new Excel Dataconfig("Excel Path");

int rows = Config.getRowcount(0);

Object[][] data = new Object [rows][2];
for(int i=o;i<rows;i++)
{
    data[i][0]=config.getData(0,i,0);
    data[i][1]=config.getData(0,i,1);
}
return data;
```

Comment: Can you please explain this line ? ` ***Excel Dataconfig config = new Excel Dataconfig("Excel Path");`

Comment: i want to read data from excel file

Comment: But as per my knowledge. Java do not allow this syntax . Please check your code. Also send me the link that you follow for read excel file.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. Fix it and get back with the issues if any.

Comment: Please paste you error/exception completely overhere first. Then only once can answer after seeing the root cause

Answer (score 0):

You start and closed your `loginjh`method.
At `TestData` method you don't have any parenthesis and no entry data (empty at quotation marks)

Answer (score 0):

Use this following code for reading the values from **Excel sheet**:

```
@DataProvider(name = “Rahul”)

public Object[][] readExcel(String sheetName) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {

//Load the Excel File

File src = new File(“./data/”+sheetName+”.xlsx”);

//Open the Book

XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(src);

//Go to Sheet

XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet(“Sheet1”);

//Row Count

int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum();

System.out.println(rowCount);

//Column Count

int column = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();

System.out.println(column);

Object[][] data = new Object[rowCount][column];

// Row – for

for (int i = 1; i <=rowCount; i++) {

XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);

//Column – for

for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {

XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);

System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());

data[i-1][j] = cell.getStringCellValue();

}

}

return data;

}

}
```